# Bundle Product price is required after Data migration from Magento1 to Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.7

I have Migrated all data from my Magento1 website to Magento2 using Magento2 data migration tool but I am facing one issue when in Magento2 website I go to Catalog > Product and Edit any Bundle Product and try to Save the Bundle Product then it give validation error like Price is required filed.
http://prntscr.com/mptlxk

but Price should not required for bundle product as dynamic price is set to Yes 
http://prntscr.com/mptl6t
So Price filed should be disabled and not required like in M1 website for bundle product its disabled and not required.

so please hlep me in this issue so I can save the bundle product without entering the price.

Thanks

Comment: Any update about this issue ?

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Comment: no for a temporary fix I have set all bundle products price to zero